# unsupported operand types error in python 3.x when trying to operate on lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming all ASCII codes are set to variables (a = 97, b = 98, etc).

```
word = eval(input("What would you like to say? "))
key = 174
print (word)
changedword = (', '.join(str(I + key) for I in word))
print ("Your encrypted string is:" + changedword)
ans1 = input("Would you like to decrypt this?")
print (ans1)
if (ans1 == "yes"):
    print (changedword)
    decryptedword = (', '.join(str(I - key) for I in changedword))
    ans2 = input(decryptedword + " was your decrypted number list. Do you 
want to translate to ASCII code?")
    if (ans2 == "yes"):
        print (', '.join(str(chr(I)) for I in decryptedword))
```

When running this code I get the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

in reference to line 11
I am aware that str and int are different, but it worked the first time I used it and I'm not sure how to fix the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know that it references encryption a lot, and I know that it's not really an encryption, but I'm new to this and I'm just playing around.

All the extra printing was for my own testing.

Comment: `str(I + key)` is not a valid operation, Since `I` is char and key is int. What are you trying to accomplish with this line?

Comment: @GarbageCollector: `I` in `str(I + key)` could be almost anything; they `eval`-ed the result of `input`, and didn't give us example inputs, expected outputs, and observed outputs (the minimum for a [MCVE]). By the time they hit `str(I - key)`, `I` is definitely a single character from a `str`, so it's a `str` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said in the question the problem line is:

```
 decryptedword = (', '.join(str(I - key) for I in changedword))
```

`key` is an int, but changedword is a str from this line:

```
changedword = (', '.join(str(I + key) for I in word))
```

You iterate through changedword `for I in changedword` and Thus `I` is also a str type.

So your problem is here `I - key` when you try to subtract an int from a str.

If you want to use the ascii value to add and subtract use the function `ord(c)` where `c` is a single character in a string. When you want to convert it back to a character use the function `chr(a)` where `a` is an ascii int

Comment: but changedword is made of ints. (I still understand the problem) so could i change the contents of "changedword" to a var and have it work? if so how could I do it?

Comment: if you know that every character in `changedword` is an `int` you could cast it as an `int` with `int()`. but this could cause bugs if you have non `int` characters

Comment: if I change it to `int()` it gives me `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: So I would recommend using `ord(c)` which gives you the ascii `int` representation. `ord(c)` will always work on characters. `int(s)` only works when `s` is a `str` that only contains integers and is prone to `TypeErrors`

Comment: oh ok. Thank you very much @JakeStephens, if you want to make what you said an official answer, I and many more would surely appreciate it.

Comment: oh I didn't realise it was you that originally typed that because shadow ranger responded first. my bad. thank you very much though.